# Service Hooks subscription trigger settings does not list my build pipeline in filters

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-service-hooks

I'm trying to set up a service hooks subscription for my yaml build pipeline on a Build completed event, but my build pipeline absolutely won't show up in the build pipeline filters. My ADO project has a huge number of build pipelines (maybe over 10,000?) and shows many of my build pipelines but it seems like there are lots missing. Is there an upper limit on the number of results the [inputValuesQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/hooks/publishers/query-input-values?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) will return? I have other yaml and classic pipelines which show up.

This is the POST request that is submitted by my browser to list all the pipelines.

```
POST https://....visualstudio.com/_apis/hooks/inputValuesQuery HTTP/1.1
Host: ....visualstudio.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 367
sec-ch-ua: " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Microsoft Edge";v="97", "Chromium";v="97"
DNT: 1
X-VSS-ReauthenticationAction: Suppress
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36 Edg/97.0.1072.62
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json;api-version=7.1-preview.1;excludeUrls=true
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
X-TFS-Session: 59fefc9d-ff32-494d-99af-8a60101618d0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
Origin: https://myproject.visualstudio.com
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: redacted
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9


{"subscription":{"consumerActionId":"serviceBusNotificationHubSend","consumerId":"azureServiceBus","consumerInputs":{},"eventType":"build.complete","publisherId":"tfs","publisherInputs":{"definitionName":"","buildStatus":"","projectId":"959adb23-f323-4d52-8203-ff34e5cbeefa"},"resourceVersion":"1.0","scope":1},"scope":10,"inputValues":[{"inputId":"definitionName"}]}
```

This is the dialog I'm referring to:

[image]